# The accessor way are different with static int and static NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below this demo code, the logical of the process is not important.

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end

static int channelIndex = 0;
static NSMutableArray *channelsDataArray = nil;

@implementation ViewController
    - (void)getSomething {
            // Append the desiredValuesDict dictionary to the following array.
            if (!self.channelsDataArray) {
                self.channelsDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: desiredValuesDict, nil];
            } else {
                [self.channelsDataArray addObject:desiredValuesDict];
                NSLog(@"channelsDataArray : %@", self.channelsDataArray);
            } 

            // This will print the result I expected.
            NSLog(@"channelIndxBefore: %i", channelIndex);
            ++channelIndex;
            NSLog(@"channelIndxAfter: %i", channelIndex);
    }


@end
```

The questions I have is that if I call the channelIndex in this way "self.channeIndex++" it will come out a warning:

> Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'NSInteger *'
>   (aka 'long *')

If I call this way "channelIndex++", which will work properly.

Strangely, I have another static NSMutableArray channelsDataArray, if I just call

```
[self.channelsDataArray addObject:desiredValuesDict];
```

It will work properly add object into the var. But if I just use

```
[channelsDataArray addObject:desiredValuesDict];
```

It will not show any warning, but the channelsDataArray will be nil, and can't assign the desiredValuesDict into it.

Question: When should I add self prefix or not? Why they are all static variable but one have to add self, another don't?

Comment: I'm guessing you have another `@interface` (in a `.h` file). Read that and all should become apparent. If not look up the difference between instance and global variables. If still stuck after that edit the question to include the other interface and someone will undoubtedly help you. Of course if there isn't another interface my guess is wrong...

Comment: @CRD You are totally right! I do have channelsDataArray declare in .h file, and declare a channelDataArray between interface () and implementation. Which is c type global variable. Thanks you so much, you can post your answer below my question, I will upvote you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Originally a comment:]*

The error suggests you have another `@interface` (in a `.h` file) and that you've declared an instance variable in that file with the same name as the global variable you have declared in the quoted file. You need to remove one of them, which depends on what you need.

HTH